# Enabling and disabling chrome commands

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a command like this:

```
 "commands": {
    "play/pause": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "MediaPlayPause"
      },
      "description": "Toggle Play / Pause",
      "global": true
    }
 }
```

Can I enable/disable it from the extension options page? If I don't use chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener, the shortcut is still active, preventing other programs from using this key.

Comment: Simply don't specify `suggested_key` and `global`.

Comment: I want for the extension user to be able to turn this off and on.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, but it's not possible.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API to programmatically toggle keyboard shortcuts defined in the manifest.

However, the user can (un)assign the suggested shortcut or change their scope from settings.

Your best bet is to instruct the user how to do it, and then open the settings interface:

```js
chrome.tabs.create({url: "chrome://extensions/configureCommands"});
```

(Note that you have to use `tabs.create` and cannot just have a link to a `chrome:` page)